# React Native white spaces in between when adding navigators

Tags: react-native

I made a header and content. But there seem to be white spaces in between when i add in navigator and I don't know how to remove it. Is it possible to remove them?

Here is my code

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
render(){
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
      <Header/>
      <AppNavigator/>
  </View>
);
}
}
```

This is my navigator

```
const AppNavigator = StackNavigator({
Cluster1: { 
    screen: Cluster1,
    },
});
```

This is my header

```
export default class Header extends React.Component {
render() {
return (
    <View>[enter image description here][1]
  <View >
  <Text>Test</Text>
  </View>
  </View>
);
}
}
```

This is my content

```
export default class Cluster1 extends Component{
render(){
    return(
        <View>
            <Text>Testing</Text>
        </View>
    );
}
}
```

Here is the output  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tyONT.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use navigatorOptions for giving header title to the navigation bar, here the white space is due to the header component and navigation bar are placed separately in JSX, so header takes its space and navigation bar takes it space which creates this white space.

```
static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Test',
    headerTitle: 'Test',
};
```

Place this inside your Cluster1 component to give navigation bar a title and remove the header component from the view.

Or another way of getting this white space removed is you can give headerMode 'none' if you want to add your own Custom Header.

```
static navigationOptions = {
         headerMode: 'none'
};
```

Note:- [You can find more info on the navigationOptions from here.](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/headers.html)

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you very much!